# How to move Bitcoins from desktop wallet to mobile wallet?

Tags: wallet, wallet-import, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have Bitcoins on my desktop wallet client.

And i now have the Bitcoin Wallet by Andreas Schildbach installed on my Android device.

IS it possible to move the desktop wallet to Android wallet?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *move* Bitcoins in the sense of a wallet [command](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Api) it would require some more technical integration.

However, the easiest thing is to scan the QR-code of your Android mobile wallet with your webcam. I use [QuickMark](http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/downloadPC.asp) for the scanning. Then you can simply copy paste the Bitcoin address to your desktop wallet and send Bitcoins to your phone via the network.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you send bitcoin from one address to another via the network, you will also pay a transaction fee.